# it is possible to retrieve an embedded resource from a referenced library

Tags: .net, xml, reflection, resources, .net-assembly

I have a library (utils) which references another library (mainlib). mainlib includes some embedded XSDs set with a build action of embedded resource.
both of these libs are in turned referenced in a web app

in the utils lib I need to read the schema from these xsd resources. I have tried using:

```
    Using s As Stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("mainlib.XSDs.mySchema.xsd")
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s)
        Return sr.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

but `GetManifestResourceStream` doesn't return anything
I even tried `GetManifestResourceNames` in an attempt to see what was in there, but again nothing returned.
is this even possible...? to get at a resource from a referenced dll from another which references that one?

any help as ever much appreciated

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up putting a static method in the referenced assembly which used

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("XSDs.mySchema.xsd")
```

which of course as it is in the correct assembly, worked fine. I can now call it from the referencing assembly and all is well.